# IAR EW: Add new device

Tags: arm, iar, ewarm

I would like to use the **ADuCM355** MCU of Analog Devices.

This device is integrated in the current IAR EW version **8.40.1** but not in my licensed version **8.11.2**.

So I'm searching for a solution to integrate the MCU to my older IAR version. I just found an [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/182378/123909) which says that it *should* be possible...

Comment: Presumably you already tried something. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Have you checked the download section at Analog Devices? sometimes the chip vendors have board-support to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple, just for guys who have the same issue.

There is a ADuCM355 [support](ftp://ftp.analog.com/pub/MicroConverter/ADuCM355/) package available. After installing it, the device can be selected in the IAR EW.

Thanks to Johan for the tip.